# Product distribution. Integration limits

Tags: probability-distributions

I have some troubles with understanding of product distribution calculation.

Consider a simple example: $f_X(x)$=$\frac{1}{2}$ for $1\le x \le 3$ and $f_Y(y)$=$\frac{1}{4}$ for $2 \le y \le 6$. Find $f_Z(z)$ if $Z=XY$.

To find pdf of $Z=XY$, I'm using the equation:

$$f_Z(z)=\int_\infty^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(\frac{z}{x})\frac{1}{|x|} dx,$$

Then, I suppose that $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f_Y(\frac{z}{x})=\frac{1}{4}$,
and getting $$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{8}\int_1^3 \frac{1}{|x|} dx=\frac{1}{8} ln(3)$$

So, I'm losing $z$ in the right part (guess, this is wrong). In addition, I'm not sure if my integration limits are correct.

May you please show how to solve this particular case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your integration needs to reflect the support of the integrand. Since the integrand includes two pdfs, the support of both must be reflected in the integration limits.

As you said, $f_X(x)$ has support for $1<x<3.$ But we need to use the fact that $f_z(z/x)$ has support for $2<z/x < 6.$ This inequality can be arranged to give a pair of conditions on $x$:$$x<z/2$$ and $$x>z/6.$$

So the integral should be $$ \frac{1}{8}\int_{\max(1,z/6)}^{\min(3,z/2)}\frac{dx}{|x|}.$$

Notice that this effectively splits up into two cases: $$2<z <6$$ and $$6 < z < 18.$$

Comment: thank you much! This is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the supports of your functions.

$\begin{align}f_Z(z) ~&=~ \int_\Bbb R \lvert x^{-1}\rvert~f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\operatorname d x
\\ &=~ \tfrac 18\int_\Bbb R\lvert{ x^{-1}}\rvert\mathbf 1_{1\leq x\leq 3}\mathbf 1_{2\leq z/x\leq 6}\operatorname d x
\\ &=~ \tfrac 18\mathbf 1_{2\leq z\leq 18} \int_\Bbb R\lvert{ x^{-1}}\rvert\mathbf 1_{1\leq x\leq 3}\mathbf 1_{z/6\leq x\leq z/2}\operatorname d x
\\ &=~ \tfrac 18\mathbf 1_{2\leq z\leq 18} \int_\Bbb R\lvert{ x^{-1}}\rvert\mathbf 1_{\max(1,z/6)\leq x\leq \min (3,z/2)}\operatorname d x
\\ &=~ \tfrac 18\mathbf 1_{2\leq z\lt 6} \int_{1}^{z/2}  x^{-1}\operatorname d x
+ \tfrac 18\mathbf 1_{6\leq z\leq 18} \int_{z/6}^3{ x^{-1}}\operatorname d x
\end{align}$

Comment: thank you much! This is what I was missing.